# Routing error: No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm trying to make the API call

> `http://localhost:56578/v1/reports`

to call my `GetReports()` method.

However I continue to get the error message in the subject.

I'm following the ms docs here via the route prefix:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#route-prefixes

What am I doing wrong?

**ReportV1Controller.cs**

```
[Authorize]
[RoutePrefix("v1/reports")]
....
....
[Route("")]
public IHttpActionResult GetReports()
```

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change from this:

```
[RoutePrefix("v1/reports")]
```

to this:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v1/reports")]
```

because of:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

See `routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"`, you said prefix for all paths will be `api`, `{controller}/{action}/{id}` are placeholders

Conclusion: if you are going to use `v1` prefix everywhere, put it instead of `api`

Answer (score 0):

What you have should work provided that you have enabled attribute routing in the `WebApiConfig`

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Attribute routing.
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(); //<-- THIS HERE

        // Convention-based routing.
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Reference [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2: **Enabling Attribute Routing**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#enabling-attribute-routing)

And assuming

```
[Authorize]
[RoutePrefix("v1/reports")]
public class ReportV1Controller : ApiController {

    //GET v1/reports
    [Route("")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetReports() {
        //...
    }
}
```