# How to fix error 404 No type was found that matches the controller named 'get'."

Tags: c#

I am trying to use the get method on my Web api so that l can get data from sql server but it is saying No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://192.168.250.113/PrimaSysWebAPI/api/get/GetUserData'.",

```
    [RoutePrefix("api/get")]
    public class GetlookUpDataController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly UserProfileRepository lookUpRepo;

        public GetlookUpDataController()
        {

            lookUpRepo = new UserProfileRepository();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetUserData")]
        public IHttpActionResult Retreive([FromBody] Profile data)
        {
            var retrieveResult = lookUpRepo.View();

            if (retrieveResult.Length > 4)
            {




                return Ok(retrieveResult);

            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("error");
                return Ok("error");
            }


        }
```

Comment: I think it must be => `http://192.168.250.113/api/get/GetUserData` without `PrimaSysWebAPI`

Comment: HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. this is what l am finding when l remove primasysWebAPI.note that l am running the API using IIS

Comment: Could you please show the routes inside `WebApiConfig.cs` ?

Answer (score 1):

Check my answer here: [my_answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55543617/5953575), so you should see how to use prefixes.

then don't forget to fix this: you have `[RoutePrefix("api/get")]` and then `[Route("GetUserData")]`,  so you are missing `/` after `api/get`

than you did not defined `/PrimaSysWebAPI`, that prefix before `/api` so not defined anywhere